# LWC for:each issue in rendering list. Cannot use calculated id

Tags: lightning-web-components, list, salesforce-id

I am trying hands on in lwc . Got stuck while I want to do something which in aura was like:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.serverResult}" var="item" indexVar="i"> 
  <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-selectedIndex="{#i}" onclick="{!c.itemSelected}">
    <span id="{#'listbox-option-unique-id-'+i+1}" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
      <span class="slds-media__figure optionIcon">
        <span class="slds-icon_container">
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">{#v.objectName}</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="slds-media__body singleRow">
        <span class="optionTitle slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{#item.text}</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Anyone can help me how to replace data-selectedindex in lwc . Also what can i use to create an id just like in span of aura . As i came to know i cannot have expression or evaluation in lwc for same. 
how can i do 
span id="{#'listbox-option-unique-id-'+i+1}"
in lwc.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_iterations) for migration from Aura to LWC. This should help you resolve this for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can either choose to use an existing value (e.g. the record Id):

```
data-record-id={item.Id}
```

Or you can add in your own:

```
@wire(...)
wireHandler({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.serverResult = data.map((record,index)=>({...record, index: `${index}`}));
  }
  if(error) {
    // do error handling
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any id associated with item as in item.id . I thik I have to add my own as you mentioned.But as I asked how can i do somehting like id="{#'listbox-option-unique-id-'+i+1}" .Elements in this are using same i value and manipulate it to get unique id by adding or concatenating , How to achieve this in lwc?

Comment: @Abha Like I said, you generate it in the JavaScript, not the expressions. I even included an example where I used `index` to create a unique value; you could make this as complicated as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks . I am trying out as you suggested .